# Suggestions for rabbit-proof plants for North Carolina

Tags: pest-control, plant-recommendations, rabbits

We live in southern North Carolina and are trying to figure out what to plant on this hill.   We put in some azaleas a month or so ago, but the bunnies have since ravaged them.  We have tried some "bunny-be-gone" and that seems to be helping, but we're not planning on having to apply a spray regularly and so we're expected them to get munched to death at some point.

The area gets sun from about 10am to 3-4pm, and the total area (pretty much all of the brown that is shown in the photo) is about 75'x 20'.  The vertical rise is about 8' from the grass to the top of the hill/bank.

We're hoping to find a combo of plants to cover this hill/bank area, but really don't have too many ideas on what to plant.  We aren't concerned about carpeting every square inch, just something that covers the majority, has some color, and doesn't require much regular maintenance.  We are truly open to all ideas.  Any suggestions?

[image: backyard pic]

Comment: A bit more detail please: how big is the area, how much sun does it get, and how big would you like the plants to end up assuming they don't get munched?

Comment: @NiallC. thanks for the feedback.  I've added some more, and if still more would be helpful, please do let me know.  ty.

Answer (score 2):

We've been battling rabbits for a few years now (in East Tennessee) and noticed they can eat almost everything, depending on the season.
Here are a few plants that have survived the carnage: lavender, peonies, sage, thyme, oregano, chamomile, carnations, raspberries (thorny), marigolds, vinca, and clematis.
From your description seems that you have about 6 hours of direct sunlight; these plants will do well in those conditions. We have them growing in both partial and full shade areas.

Here's a site that has a more detailed list: [Rabbit Resistant Plants](https://www.imustgarden.com/rabbit-resistant-plants)

Answer (score 2):

I found one thing that does discourage them (beside dogs and cats), human hair. My wife was a hairdresser and did a few friends at home at home so we had some hair available. I expect you could get hair at a local beauty or barber shop. I sprinkled it on the problem plants, expecting to rake it up in spring, but it was essentially gone after several months. Illinois rabbits love raspberries, they ate the bark ( and needles) off the canes.